# How to apply table classes to AJAX response table

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I have a table to show data from the AJAX request made. Although the data is displaying for all the three radio choices made, my prob here is that as I have classes applied on the table that holds good for pagination purposes, the data displaying does not follow the classes applied on the table i.e. I have pagination that shows 10 records each time and then next page shows next 10 records. I am posting my code here and wish to have some insight or help over this.

```html
   <?php include 'blocks/headerInc.php' ; ?>
<?php require_once "phpmailer/class.phpmailer.php";?>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.3.min.js"></script>


<?php
ob_start();                                 

$errmsg         =   "" ;

$module_id      =   '';

$query          =   '';

$date_from      =   '';

$date_to        =   '';

$status ='';

$check ='';
$disabled='';
$row='';

$sqlQuery = "SELECT * FROM tbl_user WHERE type = 3 AND status = 0 AND registration_type = 0";




?>


<div class="container pagecontainer">

  <!-- Static navbar -->

  <div class="row row-offcanvas row-offcanvas-right">

    <!--/.col-xs-12.col-sm-9-->

    <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-3 sidebar" id="sidebar">

      <div id="left_panel" class="clearfix left">



         <?php include 'blocks/leftnavInc.php' ; ?>

      </div>

    </div>

   <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-9 page-right">

  <div class="panel panel-primary"> 

        <div class="panel-heading">Candidate Approval</div>



        <div class="panel-body">



          <div class="column col-sm-offset-0">

                <form id="selection" method="GET" >

          <input type='radio'  name='users' value='unapproved' checked /> Unapproved Candidates &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
          <input type='radio'  name='users' value='approved' /> Approved Candidates &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
          <input type='radio' id='show' name='users' value='all'  /> All Candidates &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;




              <table id="example" class="table table-striped table-hover table-bordered dataTableReport dt-responsive nowrap"   cellspacing="0" width="100%">           
              <thead>

                <tr>

                  <th>S.No.</th>

                  <th>Email ID</th>

                  <th> Reference ID</th>  

                  <th>Name</th>

                  <th>Mobile No.</th>



                  <th>Registration Date</th>

                 <th>Check for Approval 

              <input type="checkbox" id="select_all" name="all_check[]" <?php echo $disabled ;?> class="checkbox" value= "<?php //echo $row['id']; ?>"> </th>
                </tr>

              </thead>

            <tbody id=datashow>  

     </tbody> 

            </table> 

           <input type="submit" name ="all_send" value="Approve" style="display: none; float: right;"  id="one" class="btn btn-success">

           </form> 



          </div>

        </div>

      </div>



      <!--/row-->

    </div>

    <!--/.sidebar-offcanvas-->

  </div>
 </div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
    $('#selection').change
    (


        function() 
        {

            var selected_value = $("input[name='users']:checked").val();

            $.ajax
            ( 
                {
                    url: "approval_ajax.php",
                    type: "POST",
                    cache: false,
                    data: { selected_value : selected_value },

                    success: function(response)
                    {
                         console.log(response);

                            var len = response.length;
                             $("#datashow").empty();
                       for(var i=0; i<len; i++){
                             var id = response[i].id;
                             var email = response[i].email;
                             var employee_id = response[i].employee_id;
                             var first_name = response[i].first_name;
                             var middle_name = response[i].middle_name;
                             var last_name = response[i].last_name;
                             var mobile = response[i].mobile;
                             var created_on = response[i].created_on;
                             var disabled = response[i].disabled;
                             var users = response[i].users;

                var tr_str = 
                    "<tr>" +
                    "<td>" + (i+1) + "</td>" +
                    "<td>" + email + "</td>" +
                    "<td>" + employee_id + "</td>" +
                    "<td>" + first_name + "&nbsp;" + middle_name + "&nbsp;" + last_name + "</td>" +
                    "<td>" + mobile + "</td>" +
                    "<td>" + created_on + "</td>" +
                    "<td><input type='checkbox' name='check[]'"  + disabled +  "value= '"  + id +  "' class='checkbox' id='select_all' ></td>" +
                      "<input type='hidden' value='"  + id +  "' name='user_id' id='user_id' >" +
                    "</tr>" ;


                $("#datashow").append(tr_str);
            }

                    }
                }
            );
        }
    );
</script>

  <script>
  $(function() {
  $('input[name="check[]"]').click(function() {
    var checkedChbx = $('[type=checkbox]:checked');
    if (checkedChbx.length > 0) {
      $('#one').show();
    } else {
      $('#one').hide();
    }
  });
});


$(document).ready(function() {

  var $submit = $("#one");
  $submit.hide();
  var $cbs = $('input[name="all_check[]"]').click(function() {
  $('input[name="check[]"]').prop('checked',$(this).is(":checked"));
    $submit.toggle($(this).is(":checked")); //use this to get the current clicked element 
  });

}); 

</script>




    <script type="text/javascript">
      var select_all = document.getElementById("select_all"); //select all checkbox
var checkboxes = document.getElementsByClassName("checkbox"); //checkbox items

//select all checkboxes
select_all.addEventListener("change", function(e){
    for (i = 0; i < checkboxes.length; i++) { 
        checkboxes[i].checked = select_all.checked;
    }
});


for (var i = 0; i < checkboxes.length; i++) {
    checkboxes[i].addEventListener('change', function(e){ //".checkbox" change 
        //uncheck "select all", if one of the listed checkbox item is unchecked
        if(this.checked == false){
            select_all.checked = false;
        }
        //check "select all" if all checkbox items are checked
        if(document.querySelectorAll('.checkbox:checked').length == checkboxes.length){
            select_all.checked = true;
        }
    });
}


    </script>

    <script>
// set users via PHP

var users = "<?php if (isset($_POST['users'])) echo $_POST['users']; ?>";
// update the HTML without interfering with other scripts
(function(users){
  // check if PH
  if (users.length) {
    // update the radio option...
    var inputTag = document.querySelector('input[value="'+users+'"]');
    if (inputTag)
      inputTag.checked = true;
    // if users is "all"
    // hide the last TD of every column
    if (users == "all") {
      var lastTh = document.querySelector('tr th:last-child');
      lastTh.style.display = "none";
      var allLastTds = document.querySelectorAll('td:last-child');
      for (var i = 0; i< allLastTds.length; i++) {
        allLastTds[i].style.display="none";
      }
    }



    if (users == "approved") {
      thInputTag = document.getElementById("select_all");
      thInputTag.setAttribute("disabled", true);
    }
     var form = document.querySelector("form");
    var inputName = document.querySelectorAll('input[name="users"]');
    for (var j=0; j<inputName.length; j++)
      inputName[j].onclick=function(){
        form.submit();
        };
        }
        })(users);

</script>



<?php include 'blocks/footerInc.php'; ?>
```

approval_ajax.php:

```
<?php
  session_start();

  require("../includes/config.php"); 
  require("../classes/Database.class.php"); 
  $db = new Database(DB_SERVER, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_DATABASE);  

  $return_arr = array();
  $status=''; 

  if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST')
  {
    $value = filter_input(INPUT_POST, "selected_value");
    if (isset($value))
    {
      $users = $value;
    } 
    else 
    {
      $users='';
    }

  switch ($users)
  {
    case "all":
      $sqlQuery = "SELECT * FROM tbl_user WHERE type =3";       
      break;
    case "approved":
      $sqlQuery = "SELECT * FROM tbl_user WHERE type =3 AND status =1";   
      break;
  }

  $sq = $db->query($sqlQuery);

  if ($db->affected_rows > 0) 
  {
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($sq)) 
    {
      $disabled = '';
      if ($status == '1') 
      {
        $disabled = "disabled = 'disabled' checked='checked' ";
      }

      $id = $row['id'];
      $email = $row['email'];
      $employee_id = $row['employee_id'];
      $first_name = $row['first_name'];
      $middle_name = $row['middle_name'];
      $last_name = $row['last_name'];
      $mobile = $row['mobile'];
      $created_on1 = $row['created_on'];
      $created_on = date("d-m-Y", strtotime($created_on1));

      $return_arr[] = array("id" => $id,
        "email" => $email,
        "employee_id" => $employee_id,
        "first_name" => $first_name,
        "middle_name" => $middle_name,
        "last_name" => $last_name,
        "mobile" => $mobile,
        "created_on" => $created_on
        "disabled" => $disabled
      );
    }
  }
  header('Content-Type: application/json', true, 200);
  echo json_encode($return_arr);
}
```

[image]

Comment: where is you `#selection` element , and what classes you are talking about you havent included any css in your source code

Comment: `<table id="example" class="table table-striped table-hover table-bordered dataTableReport dt-responsive nowrap" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
  <thead>` As you can see the classes are applied here. @MuhammadOmerAslam

Comment: i was talking about the source files, bootstrap or anyother custom css file that you are using, are there any `404` errors in `console` regarding css files that you are including .

Comment: NO I did not get any error.

Comment: Something can be done??? @MuhammadOmerAslam

Comment: i find it strange why would it not apply css when the content is updated , but the thing is you have to present the code exactly the way it is at your end to better understand the issue but in this case `ajax` is used so you cant demonstrate it here just make sure you have no unclosed `</td>` or `</div>` , if there is any live link where i can see it working maybe i can help you out

Comment: I understand your point. Must be difficult for you. If you are okay then I can send you my file.You might get a clearer idea about the same.

Comment: yeah sure just update the exact code for the html and ajax that you are using

Comment: Just updated the whole code for this page. Can you please take a look. Waiting for your response. @MuhammadOmerAslam

Comment: yeah i am looking into it , just one thing more in your complete code you are including jquery twice one in the top `ver2.2.3` and then in the footer `ver1.2.4` why is that so you should be using one of those versions, and are you using bootstrap with it for `css` ?

Comment: Ignore the `ver2.2` . I am dealing with `ver1.2.4` . And for bootstrap for `css`, yes

Comment: i just checked the code and it works at my end correctly see this [`image`](https://imgur.com/a/uLJra) it does not effect the `Css` but yes there is one thing missing a your end and that is `dataType:'json'`  which should be specified in the ajax call as you are not parsing the response in the success function , and one thing more change your `for` loop to `for In` , `for(employee in response) {` and then change all the occurrences of `response[i]` to `response[employee]` as you are iterating json so it is better to go with the for in loop , add these changes and try it.

Comment: I did not get `for(employee in response)`. Can you please notify which  line and how to change this

Comment: Yes I changed and checked. The results are clumsy and the serial number field shows values as 01,11,21 etc.

Comment: see [**`HERE`**](https://imgur.com/a/iG4kp)

Comment: can you show me the json `response` you are getting from the `console`

Comment: Yes I did the same. Doesn't helps.

Comment: ok. Justv a min. Added a screenshot. Please take a look

Comment: and you have added the `dataType:'json'` too in your ajax call is it?

Comment: this is strange the response at my end is also same https://imgur.com/a/fTmAN

Comment: Yes I have added the `data-type:'json'`. Still its not working.

Comment: Can something be done? @MuhammadOmerAslam

Comment: if you can show any live link or upload the same exact problem at some server i might be able to, but currently i am not able to replicate the issue.

Comment: Well that's not possible from my side. I am working on localhost and can't access the server

Comment: Ok, can I ask you something. Would you take a look to the header files that are included in this

Comment: `dataTables.responsive.css`, `dataTables.bootstrap.css` and in js folder `jquery.dataTables.min.js`, `dataTables.bootstrap.js`

Answer (score 0):

Well i think that id should be in quotation but in your code  `<tbody id=datashow>`  doesn't having any quotation may be you can change it like below 
`<tbody id="datashow">`

Comment: Thanks for your time. Fixed it but same results. @Varsha

Comment: Can you spot something else wrong with the code? Can we work this out?